# The type arguments for method "" cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#, moq, xunit.net

I am doing XUnit test.

Actual method:

```cs
 public async Task<HttpRequestResponse<EcapNotificationServiceResponse>>
            NotifyToUsersAsync<T>(T notification, string messageKey, string responseKey, IEnumerable<string> userIds, bool success, string errorMessage)
{
    var notifierPayload = new
    {
        NotificationType = NotificationServiceType
        .UserSpecificReceiverType.ToString(),
        ResponseKey = responseKey,
        UserIds = userIds,

        DenormalizedPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            MessageKey = messageKey,
            Result = notification,
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
            Success = success
        }),
        ResponseValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            new { Success = success }),
    };

    return await NotifyAsync(notifierPayload);
}
```

I am passing Test method

```cs
var response = await notificationService.NotifyToUsersAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<string>());
```

Error message shown this

> The type arguments for method 'Infrastructure.Contract.INotificationServiceAdapter.NotifyToUsersAsync(T, string, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, bool, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: What do you think T should be here?

Comment: Is `It.IsAny()` really XUnit, or is it Moq? Maybe check the tags of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `It.IsAny<string>()` as first argument, I assume you are testing case where `typeof(T) == typeof(string)`

```
var response = await notificationService.NotifyToUsersAsync<string>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<string>());
```